# How to read parameters passed by extjs record.set(values) in an rest service coded in java?

Tags: java, rest, extjs

I am new to extjs and am trying to implement the update operation. I tried to Google but could not find a solution.

I have form which is used for updating records in a store. For this, I am using the following code in the controller,

```
var formPanel = Ext.getCmp('displayForm');
var record = formPanel.getRecord();
var values = formPanel.getValues();
record.set(values);
companyStore.sync();
```

The `record.set()` method calls the method(i.e.rest service) pointed by the URL specified for update operation in the store’s proxy.
How can I read the `values` passed by the `record.set()` method in the rest service coded in java.

I tried with,

```
@POST
@Produces({"application/xml"})
@Path("/updateData")    
public CompanyDataService updateData(@QueryParam("company") Company companyObj){
    //code
}
```

but `companyObj` is unable to capture the parameter `values`

Answer (score 0):

There is no "values" parameter being passed. Based on the configuration of your store proxy's `Writer` (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.writer.Json), the parameters will either be a single `root` value (if `encode` configuration is true), or as individually named parameters, one per model field being persisted.

How is your `Writer` configured?

Also, just to clarify, `record.set()` doesn't trigger the proxy call unless `autoSync` is configured to true. In you example, I suspect the proxy call is happening because you explicitly call `sync()`.

Comment: Actually the proxy call is happening twice. When i debuged in the the chrome's developer tool one call was happening on record.set() and the other on sync(). 
This is my writer confiuration:

     writer: {
      type: 'xml',
      record: 'company',
      writeAllFields: true
     },

I think, in my case, the parameter is 

> individually named parameters, one per model field

Comment: So what does the actual post of data look like as you see in Chrome developer tools? The keys passed in the payload should be what you need to access server side. And given that it's a POST, the parameters might not be query params.

Comment: Thanks existdissolve, I got the problem, as you said I am using POST and it won't pass query params. I will have to accept request xml of type InputStream as a parameter and will have to add a @Consumes({ "application/xml" }) annotation to my service method.